# The app crashes when audio is playing and the device receives a phone call

Tags: objective-c, audio, avaudioplayer

The app crashes when audio is playing and the device receives a phone call. When I hang up the call and return to the application, it is blocked.

Code:

```
    NSURL *audioFileLocationURL;
    NSString *MyAudioString;
    MyAudioString = @"my-audio";
    audioFileLocationURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle]     URLForResource:MyAudioString withExtension:@"mp3"];
    NSError *error;
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:audioFileLocationURL error:&error];
    [audioPlayer setNumberOfLoops:1];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.1 target:self selector:@selector(updatemyProgress) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    if (error) {
         NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);

     } else {

         [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
         [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];

         [audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
         [audioPlayer setDelegate:self];
         [audioPlayer play];
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Done:

```
    - (void)audioPlayerBeginInterruption:(AVAudioPlayer *)player
```